# Formulario con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo varios formularios en una pagina y los estoy enviando con el método de `ajax`, como puedo identificar cuales de estos formularios fueron enviados? así tengo mi código

```
$('form').submit(function(e){}
```

Pero claro al hacer esto, me esta agarrando todos los formularios que tengo.

Comment: www.freecodecamp.com aquí tienes una de las mejores webs para aprender a programar en la web :)

Comment: no puedo agregar un id porque son valores que los estoy trayendo desde una base de datos. El me envia la informacion del formulario al cual yo le di submit pero por ejemplo tengo 2 formularios entonces el me envia la misma informacion 2 veces

Comment: especifica, a mayores detalles, mejores respuestas. Saludos :D

Comment: no se que podria decirle, porque todos los formularios tienen los mismos inputs, lo unico que le cambia es la informacion. no hay manera de colocar en ajax que se envie una sola vez?

Comment: *Tengo varios formularios en una pagina*... Parte de la pregunta debería ser mostrar el contenido de **esos varios formularios**, para ver si tienen un id único para identificarlos. Y si no los tienen, puedes dárselos si tienes acceso al código que crea los formularios. Algo así: Un formulario: `<form id="frm1" ....></form>`. Otro formulario: `<form id="frm2" ....></form>`. Otro formulario: `<form id="frm3" ....></form>`. Así, los identificas por su id. `$('form').submit(function(e){ if $(this).prop('id')=='frm1'{ //Form 1..., etc}}`

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste, le agregue un contador a cada formulario que se va incrementando dependiendo de la cantidad de formularios creados. Coloque esta parte de tu codigo 
$('form').submit(function(e){ if ($(this).prop('id')=='frm1'){ //Form 1..., etc}}

pero igual se me sigue repitiendo 10 veces el formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que estas controlando el envio de cada formulario para que se haga exclusivamente por ajax, sólo debes recorrer todos los formularios e ir enviandolos. algo así:

```
$('form').each(function(elemento){
  $(elemento).submit();
});
```

En el método que envia el formulario puedes hacer el control para saber si el formulario se envio correctamente y si obtuvo una respuesta correcta.

Si quieres hacer el control y el envio, puedes hacerlo así:

```
$('form').each(function(elemento){
  $(elemento).submit(function(){
    e.preventDefault(); //Detienes el envio normal.
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url/url/url',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Este formulario se envió correctamente');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Este formulario obtuvo un error');
            },
        });
  });
});
```

Agrégale un ID a cada formulario de forma dinámica, para que sepas cuál formulario obtuvo error y cuál se envió correctamente.
No te pongo el código porque no sé cómo generas los formularios.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En vez de:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){}
```

Colocas:

```
$('#IdDeUnoDeMisforms').submit(function(e){}

$('#IdDeOtroForm').submit(function(e){}
```

Comment: Si pero los formularios los estoy trayendo desde la base de datos, significa que son formularios dinamicos, no puedo identificarlos a cada uno con un id

Comment: hay manera de usar un condicional en jquery?, se podria hacer algo como if $(this) == $('form'){ me ejecuta el codigo del ajax }

Comment: ¿Existe alguna limitación para definir un ID durante la creación del formulario dinámicamente?

Comment: le agregue un contador a cada formulario en total son 10 y le agregue un if pero igual me sigue repitiendo la consulta 10 veces

Comment: edita tu pregunta y agrega la información de cómo estás haciendo eso :D

Answer (score -2):

en el callback intenta con e.target igual puedes pasar eso la variable e de tu callback a un console.log y checar el json pero en general es con e.target para saber que estas seteando

Comment: Hola David, mira [answer] para mejorar la respuesta. Intenta ejemplificar a la par que explicar. Un saludo